# Setup router with 2 seperate LANs, one that pipes thru VPN, one that doesn't?

Tags: networking, router, vpn, nat

I use a VPN at home for privacy, but there are times where you do want your true public IP to be known. Like for Google Maps, or pizza. I currently use a software-VPN tool on my computer for this, but there are issues: DNS leaks, some software doesn't recognize the bridged internet connection, etc.

So, I'm hoping to expand my networking knowledge a bit and reconfigure my router. I have a [Ubiquiti EdgeRouter Lite v1.4.1](http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/lanwan/lanwan-reviews/32012-first-look-ubiquiti-edgerouter-lite), currently configured to have 1 WAN port and 2 "bridged" LAN ports. I say "bridged" because the Ubiquiti routers do not come configured out of the box, you must manually set up the 3 ethernet ports to be either WAN or LAN. So the 2 LAN ports were bridged because they wouldn't connect traffic to each other by default like a normal router.

**I think that's the part I want to undo.** What I'd like is for the router to display 2 LAN ports, one which connects directly to the public internet, and the other tunnels all traffic through a VPN first. **The problem is I want both traffics to go out the same WAN.** I don't have (can't afford) dual WAN, and if this solution works I won't need it for home. I guess technically what I want is **dual NAT**, but I've never done that on this router before.

- Has anybody set up **dual NAT** on a **Ubiquiti EdgeRouter Lite** before?
- Is it possible to have **one of those NATs tunnel *ALL* of its traffic** through a VPN?

*At the end, I want to control whether I'm on VPN or not by simply enabling/disabling the appropriate network adapter on my computer.*

*EdgeOS is a fork based off the Vyatta router OS.*

Comment: I have configured several of these before, and in all cases, I have used the two LAN ports individually by assigning them to separate VLANs (and in two of the cases, multiple VLANs per interface).  Haven't configured an outbound VPN tunnel on one though so I can't actually answer your question but it sounds like it is something that *could* be done.  You will have to leave the GUI though and work on the CLI as they haven't implemented all the CLI features in the GUI yet.

Comment: @YLearn Thank you, thank you! I had totally forgotten about the VLAN feature. But you're absolutely right, that's where I should start at. After that, I'm sure I can figure out the VPN bit. I've realized this means laying a completely separate LAN overtop the existing one, but I'm ok with that. A lil' more expensive and I may need to buy another switch, but it keeps things simple. I'll be sure to post my results if I get something working that I like!